# Can't close processes using selenium threads

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, subprocess

I've been at this problem for a while now and I can't solve it. I'm making subprocesses, and then those subprocesses open more processes ( actually selenium webdrivers ). The webdriver is prone to crash, so I built this layered system so that the main process could make children, and kill/remake them when needed.

The issue I'm facing is if I run the main thread and press Ctrl+C all the children and the children of those children (the browsers) die. But when I try to do this programatically whether it be ((Popen) proc).kill(), I've tried SIGINT,SIGTERM. I've tried, .terminate, os.kill, os,killpg. No matter what I do the selenium processes won't die, but the moment I hit Ctrl+C, they all die.

Code:
Here's how I make the threads.  How could this cause issues?

`proc =  subprocess.Popen( ["python" , module_path() + "/scraper.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE ,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`

So my main question is, is there way to invoke the Ctrl+C effect that happens in terminal.  I originally tried using threads but they just kept deadlocking (why i have no idea, they had no shared memory, no dependencies). Python is not my main language, any help is a precipitated.

Thank you.
Kieran

Comment: I had the same problem once, it is very easy. All you have to do is pass closing event to the firefox browser and then to the subprocess. If you cant figure it out, I will post my answer in a couple of hours. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i solved it. I changed the program so that there was a manager process, and a child process. The manager spawned several children and the children spawned the selenium browsers. The manager waits for a child to crash and when the child does the manager kills the child which kills the selenium processes.

```
proc =  subprocess.Popen( ["python" , path + "/pythonChild.py"], preexec_fn=os.setsid, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
os.killpg( proc.pid, 9 )
```

The code above would just make it and kill it but by adding the preexec it starts a new processes group, which can then be terminated killing all its children.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: instead of creating intermediate Python script, you could just use `preexec_fn=os.setsid` on the scraper  to create a new session then `os.killpg(proc.pid, signal.SIGKILL)` (send signal to the process group `proc.pid`) should also kill all descendants. `Ctrl+C` is just `SIGINT`. A shell creates a separate process group for each pipeline.